# laravel-Snappy PDF DIVs incorrectly sized using height:11in

Tags: php, css, laravel, pdf

I'm using Laravel-snappy and am trying to absolutely position 6 columns so that 3 print on each page..

**View**

```
...
    body {
        position: relative;
    }

.col1-1 {
        text-align: right;
        background-color: #00dd00;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 11in;
    }

    .col1-2 {
        text-align: right;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #1c94c4;
        top: 0px;
        left: 270px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 11in;
    }

    .col1-3 {
        text-align: right;
        background-color: #46b8da;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 540px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 11in;
    }

    .col2-1 {
        text-align: right;
        background-color: #dd0100;
        position: absolute;
        top: 11in;
        left: 0px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 11in;
    }

    .col2-2 {
        text-align: right;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #c4770b;
        top: 11in;
        left: 270px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 11in;
    }

    .col2-3 {
        text-align: right;
        background-color: #da0073;
        position: absolute;
        top: 11in;
        left: 540px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 11in;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col1-1"></div>
<div class="col1-2"></div>
<div class="col1-3"></div>
<div class="col2-1"></div>
<div class="col2-2"></div>
<div class="col2-3"></div>
....
```

**Controller**

```
return $pdf->stream('page.pdf');

        return view('page');
```

the problem is that the columns come up short, so the 2nd row start on the 1st page...

[image: Screenshot of PDF]

I have the pagesize set to letter

```
    'pdf' => array(
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary' => 'C:\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf',
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => array('page-size'=>'letter'),
```

So I'm not really sure what to do next...

I feel like it's a scaling issue?

If I don't use Snappy, and just display the page on the screen and print the screen as a PDF, the results are much better (just a few pixels off), but of course I need the page returned as a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Snappy uses wkhtmltopdf, which in turn uses Webkit to render the HTML. (Might help you to find more info if my suggestions can't help you as your issue is probably not specifically related to Snappy.)

I think you could solve your issue by preventing the page from breaking inside the columns.. To do that you can use the following CSS on each of the columns:

```
   .col{
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
```

You might also try wrapping the 3 columns in a div and applying that css on the wrapper div.

You can also try `page-break-after: avoid` or `page-break-before: avoid`on the columns or by creating an empty div between the sets of columns and styling it with `page-break-after: always'.

Comment: I tried the empty div between sets with `page-break-after: always` from a suggestion elsewhere but with no luck.   I ended up just playing with Snappy options (that I assume are passed to wkhtmltopdf) and using `'zoom'=>1.2` everything seems to fit correctly. Though it's just a work around...